# Email Support in Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, email, jakarta-mail

Is there a mechanism to receive emails and/or establish IMAP connections in Google App Engine?  I know that GAE provides limited support for the JavaMail API (i.e. only allow to send emails).  Any workaround?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For future readers of this post: the ability to receive email has been recently added to Google App Engine. [Link to announcement](http://googleappengine.blogspot.com/2009/10/app-engine-sdk-126-released-with.html)

Answer (score 1):

Not currently, but it is on the roadmap:
http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/roadmap.html

See http://www.smtp2web.com/ (made by a googler) for a temporary solution.

Answer (score 0):

No, that is a limitation of the system (network calls are essentially limited to web requests).